# Android Room library error: Cannot find setter for field. (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I am using room library and I have below mentioned entity:

```
@Parcelize
@Entity(tableName = "tb_option")
data class OptionsTable(
        var question_id: Int? = null,
        var option_id: Int? = null,
        var option: String? = null,
        var is_selected: Int? = null,


        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var sr_no: Int = 0) : Parcelable
```

as you can see I have all the field declared as `var` but it is still showing error as:

```
error: Cannot find setter for field.
e: 

e:     private java.lang.Integer is_selected;
e:      



                     ^
```

please suggest some fix for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the initialization of `sr_no` from

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var sr_no: Int = 0
```

and the final code is:

```
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var sr_no: Int
```

worked for me because it was an auto-generated field.

Answer (score 8):

Most of the time issue is occurring because of the following:

### **Problem 1:**

**Final field**: Fields are marked with val, they are effectively final and don't have setter fields.

**Solution**: Replace the fields **val** with **var**. You might also need to initialize the fields.

### **Problem 2:**

**is keyword**: We cannot use sqllite reserved keywords line for fields naming [source](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) e.g.

The following will cause error

```
 @ColumnInfo(name = "IS_ACTIVE") var isActive
```

**Solution**: The solution is:

```
@ColumnInfo(name = "IS_ACTIVE") var active
```

Comment: It seems ridiculous to me that you cannot define class properties with a prefix like 'is'. I believe it's possible to create columns with such a prefix without troubles. Anyway, thanks a lot for this information!

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue in room orm library with kotlin java code generation.

My optional field `isFavorite` and compile time same error then I change my field name to `favorite` then compiled.

before
`var isFavorite: Int? = 0,`

working fine:
`var favorite: Int? = 0,`

Thanks