# Room Kotlin Cannot find setter for field

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Hi I'm trying to  use Room with `Kotlin` in a `MVP` based Project.

my problem is that when I create a data class and related `DAO` all the classes would generated successfully  but when a create the second data class and it's `DAO` the **`Error:Cannot find setter for field.`** thrown on rebuild command in android studio

```
@Entity(tableName = "TB_CLASSES")
class TbClass(
@ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)  var id: Int =-1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "NAME") var name: String="",
@ColumnInfo(name = "CAPTION") var caption: String="",
@ColumnInfo(name = "TYPE") var type: String="")

@Entity(tableName = "TB_FEATURE_DISA")
class TbFeatureDisa(
@ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int=-1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "FEATURE_ID") var featureId: Int=-1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "DISA_ID") var disaId: Int=-1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "IS_SOLVED") var isSolved: Int=-1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "DISA_LEVEL") var disaLevel: Double=-0.1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "RESOLVER_USER_NAME") var resolverUserName: String="",
@ColumnInfo(name = "RESOLVE_TIME") var resolveTime: Date? =null,
@ColumnInfo(name = "REPORT_VIST_ID") var reportVisitId: Int=-1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "REPORT_FAULT_ID") var reportFaultId: Int=-1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "SOLVE_VIST_ID") var solveVisitId: Int=-1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "SOLVE_SERVICE_ID") var solveServiceId: Int=-1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "SOLVE_FUALT_ID") var solveFaultId: Int=-1)
```

I've also checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44213446/cannot-find-setter-for-field-using-kotlin-with-room-database) and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47484497/android-room-library-error-cannot-find-setter-for-field-kotlin?rq=1) but none of them worked for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The problem is related to property naming.

The following causes errors at compile time:

```
 @ColumnInfo(name = "IS_SOLVED") var isSolved
```

but when I changed the above to the following, the error is resolved:

```
 @ColumnInfo(name = "IS_SOLVED") var solved
```

We cannot use SQLite reserved keywords [line](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) for field naming.
I'm using Room version 1.0.0 and kotlin version 1.1.51.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `data class` which will provide `setters` and `getters` for properties as in

```
@Entity(tableName = "TB_CLASSES")
data class TbClass( //< add data prior to class
@ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)  var id: Int =-1,
@ColumnInfo(name = "NAME") var name: String="",
@ColumnInfo(name = "CAPTION") var caption: String="",
@ColumnInfo(name = "TYPE") var type: String="")
```

**TbFeatureDisa**

```
    @Entity(tableName = "TB_FEATURE_DISA")
    data class TbFeatureDisa(
    @ColumnInfo(name = "ID")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true) var id: Int=-1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "FEATURE_ID") var featureId: Int=-1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "DISA_ID") var disaId: Int=-1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "IS_SOLVED") var isSolved: Int=-1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "DISA_LEVEL") var disaLevel: Double=-0.1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "RESOLVER_USER_NAME") var resolverUserName: String="",
    @ColumnInfo(name = "RESOLVE_TIME") var resolveTime: Date? =null,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "REPORT_VIST_ID") var reportVisitId: Int=-1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "REPORT_FAULT_ID") var reportFaultId: Int=-1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "SOLVE_VIST_ID") var solveVisitId: Int=-1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "SOLVE_SERVICE_ID") var solveServiceId: Int=-1,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "SOLVE_FUALT_ID") var solveFaultId: Int=-1)
```

Answer (score -3):

For the folks who lack attention like me and stumbled here via Google, using `val` instead of `var` gives the same error message.